# I was working on highcharts and react and want to built something like this with highcharts. Is it possible?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqRRV.png)

Which type of graph will give this kind of functionality in Highcharts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be able to achieve it by implementing `bubble series` as a base and adding those correct markers as a scatter point but with customizing them. On the SO you can find many ways how to achieve it, for example: [Highcharts scatter set markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768419/highcharts-scatter-set-markers)

Bubble demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bubble